# Web application hosted on Firebase works on Android but doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, firebase, web-applications

I'm developing a web application, this application is supposed to work on Android and iOS. I wrote the code in JavaScript and used OnsenUI and JQuery. I use Firebase Real-time database and the application is also hosted on Firebase.

The problem is that the application works properly on Android and also on Chrome both on Windows and macOs but when I try to run it on an iPhone it doesn't work (neither on safari nor chrome). When I run it the UI loads but isn't filled with the data downloaded from the database.

What could be the problem? This is my first web application so I don't have any experience.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try using the remote Web Inspector to debug the page from your mac. On your iPhone `Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector`. Then connect your phone to your mac and see if you can see any errors in Safari debugger.

Comment: I opened the web inspector but there are no errors...